# How do I get a Epson Aculaser C1600 working?

Tags: drivers, printing

Anyone managed to install this printer? I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: I spoke to Epson and they have confirmed that they don't support linux OS what-so-ever. Got a dead C1600 and it's back to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with Ubuntu 10.10 and initialized my printer Epson aculaser C1600 with the driver of konica minolta magicolor 1600w:

system->system managment(administation)->printer.

Then ads your Epson printer, then select the driver Komica Minolta and the look for Magicolor 1600w.

After then you print the testing page. Be a little patient. If the page is printed in gray and black, then change  the printing option fom "monochrome" to "Color - Best Compromise".

Much fun!

Comment: great! I was about to sell the printer! Danke Sehr!

Comment: Thank you for solution. It works (10.10). The only issue I noticed was a PDF printing from Evince. Epson makes 2 pages then yellow indicator start blinking. When I press "Clear" button, Epson print another 2 pages and so on. From LibreOffice everything works fine !

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help, but [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=285558) suggests that manually installing it as a HP LaserJet 4 will make it work. I assume they meant to install through the `hplip` drivers. Just manually specify the driver in the printer dialogue.

I'll be honest, I've no idea what the guts of this machine really are compatible but it's worth a punt.

Comment: unfortunately it's for the Actionlaser 1600, a much older model... I also found the thread, it didn't work :/

Comment: the guys from http://www.avasys.jp/ who make the linux drivers of epson just confirmed to me that they won't be drivers for this model. Don't buy the aculaser C1600!